# doing an each function with ajax to return multiple data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, each

I have a php function that does a loop, and the loop pretty much shoots out a list of names, and then if you click on the name, I've developed some slide down content to show information on that name. And I have some pagination set up where its supposed to go inside that container.

But, its not working, and I'm thinking that its because its not going to know to load into all the names.

```
function loadData(page){
                //loading_show(); 
                dataString = "page="+page+"&name_list="+name_list;          
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "ajax_name.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                            $("div.names").html(msg);

                    }
                });
     }
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
```

so pretty much loadData is supposed to load into multiple name containers. So the PHP is theres a while loop creating multiple names with multiple containers for the data thats supposed to be loaded.

Any idea as to how to get this loadData to load within each div? Do I have to do an each? but i'm not quite sure how to incorporate it in this function.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you can retrieve your data. Can you retrieve everything you need in one call or do you need to provide different urls for everything?

Comment: I can retrieve everything i need in one call (`loadData(1)`). This will set everything once to first page on document ready. However, I have a while loop which returns different names, so the `name_list` in ajax is getting those names, and I'm just putting each return data from this ajax to the correct names from the while loop

Comment: I would retrieve all your data in one call. How you put that data into the destination markup depends on your markup. Looping might be difficult if your markup isn't in something that lends itself to identifying through a looping index. What does the markup for your destination containers look like?

Comment: My loop actually has a lot of stuff going on, but its pretty much a while loop and fetching through mysql to get out the information. I do have id's set for each container that gets created through the while loop but I'm just not sure how to put it into the function

Answer (score 0):

I would json encode all of the data that you need to return from the server using the built-in json_encode() method, then loop through all of the returned data.

Comment: can you give an example of how json_encode would work with this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with JSON? If not, basically, it is a lightweight way of transferring data from server to client, and it can easily be parsed into an object by javascript. You could you your server-side query to push all of the results into an array, json_encode() that array, and return the encoded data through an 'echo' statement. From there, you would be able to do a for-each loop for each item in the returned JSON object.